# CSS not loading in Spring Boot when running from jar

Tags: css, spring, jar, program-entry-point

I built a fat jar and when running it from a command line, no CSS loads.

java -jar -Dserver.port=9000 target/1or2clicks-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

If instead, I simply run the psvm in my IDE, it works fine.  I have double checked my folder hierarchy main/resources/static/css and it all looks fine.

Should the contents of my 1or2clicks-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar under BOOT-INF/classes look like this:

[image]

Comment: Where did you place the CSS?

Comment: \src\main\resources\static\css

Comment: and how do you reference the CSS? Please show some code

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />  Strange thing is, the app works fine when running through the main method!  You know, it's always these little bits that take the most time :)

Comment: You must use /css/main.css

Comment: I added the preceding /, rebuilt the jar and it is behaving the same way

Comment: What do you use for your front-end? Static HTML? A template engine? Or is it even a SPA or something?

Comment: is this a static html page where you using the stylesheet or a thymeleaf template?

Comment: It is an html file using thymeleaf

Comment: try running it as ```java -jar -Dserver.port=9000 target/ROOT.jar```

Comment: There is no ROOT.jar in /target

Comment: @stanlick rename your jar file to ROOT.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who chimed in.  I discovered my issue a few minutes ago as I was reviewing the MANIFEST.MF included inside the fat jar.  I was running this jar via

java -jar -Dserver.port=9000 target/1or2clicks-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

and CSS was not loading.  Since the manifest revealed this was a runnable jar, I simply ran the jar via

\1or2clicks\target>1or2clicks-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

and it works perfectly!